# Criação de um Header que é utilizado na comunicação de uma WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, header

Eu estou a criar um programa que faz a comunicação com uma webapi e está me a dar este erro na criação do header.

Eu estou a usar isto para criar o header :

```
var tempo = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("teste");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Date"+ tempo);
```

O output é este :

> Date2017-09-08T15:25:53Z

Eu queria que fosse este:

> Date: 2017-09-08T15:25:53Z

Já testei também o seguinte código:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add($"Date: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")}");
```

Esse código gerou o seguinte erro :

> System.ArgumentException: 'O cabeçalho 'Date' tem de ser modificado
>   com a propriedade ou o método adequado.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não é a string, você precisa especificar qual o nome do header:

```
var tempo = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("teste");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("MeuHeader", "Date: " + tempo);
```

Assim vai funcionar também:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers["Meuheader"] = "Date: " + tempo;
```

Eu só não entendi se você queria um cabeçalho com nome de "Date" ou estava tentando concatenar o valor.

Comment: Como eu faço para aparecer só o Date: + o tempo

Comment: Sem aparecer a traz o Meuheader

Comment: Até onde eu sei o header deve possuir um nome, só toma cuidado com o nome que você da, existe alguns padrões a se seguir caso contrário o firewall pode acabar ignorando ele.

Comment: Eu queria que o meu header ficasse assim por exemplo : 'Date: 2016-06-29T12:00:00Z'